How does Tarski's axiom imply the axiom of choice?
PlanetMath defines Tarski's axiom as follows: $\forall s \exists u$ such that

$s \in u$
$(\forall x \in u) (\forall y \subseteq x) (y \in u)$
$(\forall x \in u) (\mathscr{P}(x) \in u)$
$(\forall x \subseteq u) (|x| < |u| \to x \in u)$

How does this imply the axiom of choice?
This answer cites a proof that $\mathsf{A}_2 \to \mathsf{Choice}$, where $\mathsf{A}_2$ is the statement defined on page 180 here. (In fact, the paper proves that $\mathsf{A}_2 \leftrightarrow \mathsf{Choice}$.) But how does $\mathsf{TA} \to \mathsf{A}_2$?

The thing is that if $x$ satisfies conditions (2)–(4), then $x$ is a model of $\sf ZF_2$. So, it follows, that it must be some $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$. However, if $|V_\kappa|\neq\kappa$, then $\kappa<|V_\kappa|$, and by (4), it must be that $\kappa\in V_\kappa$, which is impossible.
So, as a consequence, it must be that $V_\kappa$ has size $\kappa$, so $V_\kappa\models\sf ZFC_2$, rather than just $\sf ZF_2$. Now, if you require that every $s$ lies in some $V_\kappa$ where $\sf AC$ holds, then $\sf AC$ holds in the universe.

Can you clarify this step? $|V_\kappa| = \kappa \Longrightarrow V_\kappa \vDash \mathsf{ZFC}_2$.

If $V_\kappa$ is already a model of $\sf ZF$ and it has size $\kappa$, then it can be well ordered. So all of its elements can be well ordered. So they can be well ordered inside $V_\kappa$ itself, since these well orders must have low rank.
